# AngularJS 2 error: enableProdMode is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm use https://angular.io/guide/quickstart to start learn Angular2, but I notice there's console log "Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode." So I added to main.ts as following.

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
enableProdMode();
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Now the browser has error

> enableProdMode is not defined(…)

So I found this article https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6096.

Looks like I'm doing it right, and works on others, so maybe my package files  or npm modules has something is wrong? please help, or do you know which module is using enableProdMode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you missed to import `enableProdMode`

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Glad to know that, Thanks. Could you please accept & upvote my answer.. 